# Wp-strap Wordpress plugin boilerplate prod output is empty

Tags: wordpress, npm, webpack, hadoop-yarn

I want to use this boilerplate https://github.com/wp-strap/wordpress-plugin-boilerplate to create Wordpress plugins .

The issue is `yarn prod` results in empty output (css files in public folder are empty) .

`Yarn dev`is working fine.

Bellow are my config files :

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "wordpress-webpack-workflow",
  "version": "1.1.4",
  "author": "WP-Strap",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/wp-strap/wordpress-webpack-workflow",
  "description": "Modern WebPack workflow for WordPress front-end development and testing (plugins & themes) with handy tools included.\n",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/wp-strap/wordpress-webpack-workflow.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/wp-strap/wordpress-webpack-workflow/issues"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "prod": "webpack --env NODE_ENV=production --env production",
    "prod:watch": "webpack --env NODE_ENV=production --env production --watch",
    "dev": "webpack --env NODE_ENV=development",
    "dev:watch": "webpack --env NODE_ENV=development --watch",
    "eslint": "eslint assets/src/js/**/*.js",
    "eslint:fix": "eslint assets/src/js/**/*.js --fix",
    "stylelint": "stylelint assets/src/**/**/*.{css,scss,pcss}",
    "stylelint:fix": "stylelint assets/src/**/**/*.{css,scss,pcss} --fix",
    "prettier": "prettier assets/src/js/**/*.js",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --write assets/src/js/**/*.js",
    "translate": "wp-pot --src '**/**/**/*.php' --dest-file 'languages/report-error.pot' --package 'report-error' --domain 'report-error' --last-translator 'WP SCRIPT LAB <wpscriptlab@gmail.com>' --team 'WP SCRIPT LAB <wpscriptlab@gmail.com>' --bug-report 'wpscriptlab.com'"
  },
  "babel": {
    "extends": "./webpack/babel.config.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "./webpack/.eslintrc.js"
    ]
  },
  "prettier": "./webpack/.prettierrc.js",
  "stylelint": {
    "ignoreFiles": [
      "./assets/public/css/**/*.css",
      "./vendor/**/**/*.css",
      "./node_modules/**/**/*.css",
      "./tests/**/**/*.css"
    ],
    "extends": [
      "./webpack/.stylelintrc.js"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@wordpress/eslint-plugin": "^7.4.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.17.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "glob-all": "^3.2.1",
    "image-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "imagemin-gifsicle": "^7.0.0",
    "imagemin-jpegtran": "^7.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^8.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "node-sass-magic-importer": "^5.3.2",
    "postcss": "^8.2.4",
    "postcss-advanced-variables": "^3.0.1",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.0",
    "postcss-import-ext-glob": "^2.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.3",
    "postcss-nested-ancestors": "^2.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.8.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.18.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.12.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpackbar": "^5.0.0-3",
    "wp-pot-cli": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "wordpress",
    "workflow",
    "webpack",
    "theme",
    "plugin",
    "WebPack",
    "BrowserSync",
    "PostCSS",
    "Autoprefixer",
    "PurgeCSS",
    "BabelJS",
    "Eslint",
    "Stylelint",
    "SCSS",
    "WP-Pot"
  ]
}
```

*composer.json*

```
{
    "name": "wpstrap/wordpress-plugin-boilerplate",
    "description": "Wordpress Plugin Boilerplate",
    "version": "0.3.1",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "type": "wordpress-plugin",
    "license": "MIT",
    "homepage": "https://wp-strap.com",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "ReportError\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "phpcs": "./vendor/bin/phpcs"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "micropackage/requirements": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.1",
        "wp-coding-standards/wpcs": "*",
        "automattic/phpcs-neutron-ruleset": "^3.3",
        "phpcompatibility/phpcompatibility-wp": "^2.1"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "wordpress",
        "plugin",
        "boilerplate",
        "framework"
    ],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "WP-Strap",
            "email": "hello@wp-strap.com",
            "homepage": "https://wp-strap.com"
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true
        }
    }
}
```

*webpack.config.js*

```
/**
 * This is a main entrypoint for Webpack config.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
const path = require( 'path' );

// Paths to find our files and provide BrowserSync functionality.
const projectPaths = {
    projectDir:        __dirname, // Current project directory absolute path.
    projectJsPath:     path.resolve( __dirname, 'assets/src/js' ),
    projectScssPath:   path.resolve( __dirname, 'assets/src/scss' ),
    projectImagesPath: path.resolve( __dirname, 'assets/src/images' ),
    projectOutput:     path.resolve( __dirname, 'assets/public' ),
    projectWebpack:    path.resolve( __dirname, 'webpack' ),
};

// Files to bundle
const projectFiles = {
    // BrowserSync settings
    browserSync: {
        enable: true, // enable or disable browserSync
        host:   'localhost',
        port:   3000,
        mode:   'proxy', // proxy | server
        server: { baseDir: [ 'public' ] }, // can be ignored if using proxy
        proxy:  'report-error.local',
        // BrowserSync will automatically watch for changes to any files connected to our entry,
        // including both JS and Sass files. We can use this property to tell BrowserSync to watch
        // for other types of files, in this case PHP files, in our project.
        files:  '**/**/**.php',
        reload: true, // Set false to prevent BrowserSync from reloading and let Webpack Dev Server take care of this
        // browse to http://localhost:3000/ during development,
    },
    // JS configurations for development and production
    projectJs: {
        eslint:   true, // enable or disable eslint  | this is only enabled in development env.
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        entry:    {
            frontend: projectPaths.projectJsPath + '/frontend.js',
            backend:  projectPaths.projectJsPath + '/backend.js',
        },
        rules:    {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
        }
    },
    // CSS configurations for development and production
    projectCss: {
        postCss:   projectPaths.projectWebpack + '/postcss.config.js',
        stylelint: true, // enable or disable stylelint | this is only enabled in development env.
        filename:  'css/[name].css',
        use:       'sass', // sass || postcss
        // ^ If you want to change from Sass to PostCSS or PostCSS to Sass then you need to change the
        // styling files which are being imported in "assets/src/js/frontend.js" and "assets/src/js/backend.js".
        // So change "import '../sass/backend.scss'" to "import '../postcss/backend.pcss'" for example
        rules:    {
            sass:    {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i
            },
            postcss: {
                test: /\.pcss$/i
            }
        },
        purgeCss: { // PurgeCSS is only being activated in production environment
            paths: [ // Specify content that should be analyzed by PurgeCSS
                __dirname + '/assets/src/js/**/*',
                __dirname + '/templates/**/**/*',
                __dirname + '/template-parts/**/**/*',
                __dirname + '/blocks/**/**/*',
                __dirname + '/*.php',
            ]
        }
    },
    // Source Maps configurations
    projectSourceMaps: {
        // Sourcemaps are nice for debugging but takes lots of time to compile,
        // so we disable this by default and can be enabled when necessary
        enable: true,
        env:    'dev-prod', // dev | dev-prod | prod
        // ^ Enabled only for development on default, use "prod" to enable only for production
        // or "dev-prod" to enable it for both production and development
        devtool: 'source-map' // type of sourcemap, see more info here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/
        // ^ If "source-map" is too slow, then use "cheap-source-map" which struck a good balance between build performance and debuggability.
    },
    // Images configurations for development and production
    projectImages: {
        rules: {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        },
        // Optimization settings
        minimizerOptions: {
            // Lossless optimization with custom option
            // Feel free to experiment with options for better result for you
            // More info here: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/image-minimizer-webpack-plugin/
            plugins: [
                [ 'gifsicle', { interlaced: true } ],
                [ 'jpegtran', { progressive: true } ],
                [ 'optipng', { optimizationLevel: 5 } ],
                [ 'svgo', {
                    plugins: [
                        { removeViewBox: false, },
                    ],
                }, ],
            ],
        }
    }
}

// Merging the projectFiles & projectPaths objects
const projectOptions = {
    ...projectPaths, ...projectFiles,
    projectConfig: {
        // add extra options here
    }
}

// Get the development or production setup based
// on the script from package.json
module.exports = env => {
    if ( env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ) {
        return require( './webpack/config.production' )( projectOptions );
    } else {
        return require( './webpack/config.development' )( projectOptions );
    }
};
```

*config.base.js*

```
/**
 * This holds the configuration that is being used for both development and production.
 * This is being imported and extended in the config.development.js and config.production.js files
 *
 * @since 1.1.0
 */
const magicImporter        = require( 'node-sass-magic-importer' ); // Add magic import functionalities to SASS
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin' ); // Extracts the CSS files into public/css
const BrowserSyncPlugin    = require( 'browser-sync-webpack-plugin' ) // Synchronising URLs, interactions and code changes across devices
const WebpackBar           = require( 'webpackbar' ); // Display elegant progress bar while building or watch
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require( 'image-minimizer-webpack-plugin' ); // To optimize (compress) all images using
const CopyPlugin           = require( "copy-webpack-plugin" ); // For WordPress we need to copy images from src to public to optimize them

module.exports = ( projectOptions ) => {

    /**
     * CSS Rules
     */
    const cssRules = {
        test:    projectOptions.projectCss.use === 'sass' ? projectOptions.projectCss.rules.sass.test : projectOptions.projectCss.rules.postcss.test,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|vendor)/,
        use:     [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
            "css-loader",  // Translates CSS into CommonJS
            {  // loads the PostCSS loader
                loader:  "postcss-loader",
                options: require( projectOptions.projectCss.postCss )( projectOptions )
            }
        ],
    };

    if ( projectOptions.projectCss.use === 'sass' ) { // if chosen Sass then we're going to add the Sass loader
        cssRules.use.push( { // Compiles Sass to CSS
            loader:  'sass-loader',
            options: {
                sassOptions: { importer: magicImporter() }  // add magic import functionalities to sass
            }
        } );
    }

    /**
     * JavaScript rules
     */
    const jsRules = {
        test:    projectOptions.projectJs.rules.test,
        include: projectOptions.projectJsPath,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|vendor)/,
        use:     'babel-loader' // Configurations in "webpack/babel.config.js"
    };

    /**
     * Images rules
     */
    const imageRules = {
        test: projectOptions.projectImages.rules.test,
        use:  [
            {
                loader: 'file-loader',// Or `url-loader` or your other loader
            },
        ],
    }

    /**
     * Optimization rules
     */
    const optimizations = {};

    /**
     * Plugins
     */
    const plugins = [
        new WebpackBar( // Adds loading bar during builds
            // Uncomment this to enable profiler https://github.com/nuxt-contrib/webpackbar#options
            // { reporters: [ 'profile' ], profile: true }
        ),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin( { // Extracts CSS files
            filename: projectOptions.projectCss.filename
        } ),
        new CopyPlugin( { // Copies images from src to public
            patterns: [ { from: projectOptions.projectImagesPath, to: projectOptions.projectOutput + '/images' }, ],
        } ),
        new ImageMinimizerPlugin( { // Optimizes images
            minimizerOptions: projectOptions.projectImages.minimizerOptions,
        } ),
    ];
    // Add browserSync to plugins if enabled
    if ( projectOptions.browserSync.enable === true ) {
        const browserSyncOptions = {
            files: projectOptions.browserSync.files,
            host:  projectOptions.browserSync.host,
            port:  projectOptions.browserSync.port,
        }
        if ( projectOptions.browserSync.mode === 'server' ) {
            Object.assign( browserSyncOptions, { server: projectOptions.browserSync.server } )
        } else {
            Object.assign( browserSyncOptions, { proxy: projectOptions.browserSync.proxy } )
        }
        plugins.push( new BrowserSyncPlugin( browserSyncOptions, { reload: projectOptions.browserSync.reload } ) )
    }

    return {
        cssRules: cssRules, jsRules: jsRules, imageRules: imageRules, optimizations: optimizations, plugins: plugins
    }
}
```

*config.production.js*

```
/**
 * Webpack configurations for the production environment
 * based on the script from package.json
 * Run with: "npm run prod" or or "npm run prod:watch"
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
const glob           = require( 'glob-all' );
const PurgecssPlugin = require( 'purgecss-webpack-plugin' )  // A tool to remove unused CSS

module.exports = ( projectOptions ) => {

    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';  // Set environment level to 'production'

    /**
     * The base skeleton
     */
    const Base = require( './config.base' )( projectOptions );

    /**
     * CSS rules
     */
    const cssRules = {
        ...Base.cssRules, ...{
            // add CSS rules for production here
        }
    };

    /**
     * JS rules
     */
    const jsRules = {
        ...Base.jsRules, ...{
            // add JS rules for production here
        }
    };

    /**
     * Image rules
     */
    const imageRules = {
        ...Base.imageRules, ...{
            // add image rules for production here
        }
    }

    /**
     * Optimizations rules
     */
    const optimizations = {
        ...Base.optimizations, ...{
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    styles: {  // Configured for PurgeCSS
                        name:    'styles',
                        test:    /\.css$/,
                        chunks:  'all',
                        enforce: true
                    }
                }
            }
            // add optimizations rules for production here
        }
    }

    /**
     * Plugins
     */
    const plugins = [
        ...Base.plugins, ...[
            new PurgecssPlugin( { // Scans files and removes unused CSS
                paths: glob.sync( projectOptions.projectCss.purgeCss.paths, { nodir: true } ),
            } ),
            // add plugins for production here
        ]
    ]

    /**
     * Add sourcemap for production if enabled
     */
    const sourceMap = { devtool: false };
    if ( projectOptions.projectSourceMaps.enable === true && (
        projectOptions.projectSourceMaps.env === 'prod' || projectOptions.projectSourceMaps.env === 'dev-prod'
    ) ) {
        sourceMap.devtool = projectOptions.projectSourceMaps.devtool;
    }

    /**
     * The configuration that's being returned to Webpack
     */
    return {
        mode:         'production',
        entry:        projectOptions.projectJs.entry, // Define the starting point of the application.
        output:       {
            path:     projectOptions.projectOutput,
            filename: projectOptions.projectJs.filename
        },
        devtool:      sourceMap.devtool,
        optimization: optimizations,
        module:       { rules: [ cssRules, jsRules, imageRules ], },
        plugins:      plugins,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around i found that the empty output was caused by **Purge CSS - purgecss-webpack-plugin**. It removes unused css.

So the issue was that even though i added scss code in source files, it wasn't used anywhere in php files source folder.

So if i want to output the following css code :

```
.body {
   color: red;
}
```

I need to add that class in php templates inside the src folder for plugin structure.

[image: class declaration in php]
Results in successful output of css after `yarn prod` command :

[image: yarn prod successful output]